# NoScript goes berserk in Iran (Request filtered by ABE)

Tags: censorship

For years now NoScript has provided good services to me and as I am in Iran now I am quite surpirsed which kinds of messages I'm getting from it.

Since my arrivial here I have tried three different ISPs and get the same message with any of them for most of the pages I am using:
[image]

> The request [...] was filtered by ABE  Deny

Usually I get these kind of messages when I am in a hotel which requires a web-login for its Wi-Fi. But here NoScript brings up this message almost constantly. (Strangely not right now here at security.stackexchange).

For what I can tell now:

- Tor doesn't work
- VPN doesn't work (even with changed ports)
- Most pages aren't accessible any more
- DNS-Entries are fakes/Censored (https://jhalderm.com/pub/papers/iran-foci13.pdf)
- And from my
  personal experience several constraints in URLs are on a black-list
  (Proxy, VPN, ...)

As I understand ABE is some sort of "firewall" which blocks Cross-Site-Scripting I assume the worst...

If someone has more ideas what's really going on, please share your information.

Comment: Why do you think it is NoScript?